# How to dim (and un-dim) display in automator

Tags: automator, bash, command-line, error, display

For those that are interested in the final script you can get it [here](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B26Sf8IL7PUgM2ZlN2FkMmEtZjRjZC00ZmZiLWEyMmItZTEzZWQ3ZTc1ZDA5&hl=en_US)

### original question

---

I am trying to make a alarmclock script to wake me up. but I can't figure out how to change the screen brightness in automator.[image: here is my workflow without brightness]

I found a way to control brightness with the commandline. but I can't get it to work in automator

> I'm the original author of the code listed in this hint. I originally wrote it for two reasons: first, to adjust brightness automatically by location on my iBook G4, which had no ambient light sensor, and second, so I could have my laptop turn on the backlight when a long operation finished, providing a quiet form of notification I could use while at a seminar.
>   http://sabi.net/nriley/software/brightness.zip is 4-way universal, 10.5+. I compiled it under 10.6 with:...
>   ([see full forum page](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090901021817717) )

but when I try to use

```
brightness 0
```

or

```
brightness 1
```

I get an error in automator.
[image: error]

am I using the run shell script wrong?
could this be done easier in apple script?
is there a alltogether easyer way to do this?

**I need to turn the brightness up and down in automator how is this done?**

**Update**  I tried the apple script method you mentioned and it....showed the overlay that shows when the key is pressed but did nothing else

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you install the “brightness” command? Even if you've set up your PATH in the shell `rc` scripts, it may not take effect for these commands because Automator isn't run *from* a shell. (You can set environment for all programs including GUI using `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist`, but I wouldn't recommend fiddling with PATH just for this.)

I suggest changing your Automator workflow to use the full path to where it's installed, e.g.

```
/usr/local/bin/brightness 1
```

Comment: it is installed there as stated in above tutorial http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090901021817717

Comment: @mjrider: I don't see a specific place mentioned in the main text, but I do see `/usr/local/bin` and `/Library` (not a good idea) mentioned. But *neither of these places is in `PATH` by default*, so you must use the full path to *where you actually installed it*.

Comment: @kevin reid http://www.screencast.com/t/Od4RTdNt5NRY I did place it in /user/local/bin. I can run this command from terminal right off the bat without any other command. and it works find http://www.screencast.com/t/Bkyv91LPySN

Comment: That's because you have `/usr/local/bin` configured in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. Programs not running from a Terminal will not have these settings. **Use the full path to the command in your Automator configuration.**

Comment: OOOHHHH so insted of "brightness 1" use "/usr/local/bin/brightness 1" IN THE SCRIPT in automator? (wasn't quite clear in your answer thats what you ment)

Comment: beautiful that works...I still would edit your answer to make it more clear thats what you ment. thanks

Answer (score 1):

To use the command line way you tried, you have to install some software. You can download it, and find install directions, [here](http://mattdanger.net/2008/12/adjust-mac-os-x-display-brightness-from-the-terminal/).

Another option: You can run an AppleScript from your Automator workflow to press the brightness up/down keys. Up:

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 107
```

Down:

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 113
```

Note: you may have to [Enable Access for Assistive Devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hulAF.jpg) for the AppleScript to work.

Comment: I belive I have installed it...I CAN go to the terminal and say 
brightness 0
and have the screen go dark... but it won't work in the script...but I will try this other way and let you know

Comment: also when I use either of those scripts I JUST see the sun that shows how bright the screen is...without it changing at all... =( I think I am doing something wrong...

Comment: @mjrider Can you take a screenshot of just the Run Shell Script action for me? That's weird with the scripts; they now do that on mine too. I wonder why they aren't working...

Comment: http://www.screencast.com/t/f6g9CSMDmf8 I get the same results if I use "pass input as argument"

Comment: This no longer works in macOS Sierra

Answer (score 1):

Try having the automator run this AppleScript. It works for me!

```
set brightness_level to 1.0

tell application "System Events"
    tell application "System Preferences" to reveal the anchor "displaysDisplayTab" of pane named "Displays"
    tell slider 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences"
        set value to brightness_level
    end tell
end tell
```