# What key code maps to external USB brightness up/down keys?

Tags: macos, keyboard, command-line, automation, keybindings

I am writing a script and I need to figure out current key codes for brightness up and down with an external keyboard.

I know the standard for a MacBook is 107 and 113, though as soon as I connect a different bigger apple keyboard, those changes to 145 and 144.

I need to be able to get this information out of the terminal as I'm scripting things there.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The 'System keys' don't seem to have a Key Code equivalent, they are actioned below the OS-level. Try [Key Codes](http://manytricks.com/keycodes/) (freeware)

Comment: Thank you, I tried this but it seems like the brightness keys are silent.

Comment: Precisely. All the system keys seem to be :( Did you see this… http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16622/how-to-dim-and-un-dim-display-in-automator

Answer (score 0):

Simply save these lines (first one makes your screen darker, second one brighter) in one Applescript .scpt file each:

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 107

tell application "System Events" to key code 113
```

and execute them with

```
/usr/bin/osascript /path/to/the/script
```

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the key code is not the same with an external keyboard for example, read my question again.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I'll update my answer once I get ahold of my external keyboard.